# Android - can I mute currently playing audio applications?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

Hi I'm new to this.  My self-teaching project is a small application which plays an audio news stream.  To be effective, the application really needs to interrupt any currently playing media players (eg: Last FM, Imeem, music player, Spotify etc).

I don't know what will be playing or what application will be playing it, but I want to ask them all to pause until I've done.  Sounds rather bold, I know, but it must be possible, because when there's an incoming call, that's basically what happens.

Can I send a message to all audio players asking them to pause for a moment?  Could I spoof an incoming call, just for the time it takes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Audio handling on Android is going to be pretty horrible for a while.  The APIs are pretty weird, poorly documented, and keep changing/deprecating/breaking between versions.  Even the `AudioManager` code has FIXMEs in it.

Anyway, there are several stream types in Android (music, notifications, phone calls, etc.) and applications are meant to choose the appropriate one for playback.  I imagine the majority of Android apps should use the music/media type (`STREAM_TYPE_MUSIC`).  You set this on your `MediaPlayer` using the `setAudioStreamType` method.

The SDK does allow you to set a single stream *type* as solo — causing all other streams to be muted — but I don't believe you can identify the audio being played back by particular applications and somehow pause/unpause it.  Music applications in general will use the `PhoneStateListener` to pause themselves when a call comes in.

So in your case, you could "borrow" the phone call stream for your `MediaPlayer` and use the method call `AudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true)` when playback begins, then un-solo the stream with `false` when playback or your `Activity` is done.

I can tell you that this works, but I can't remember offhand whether you need to also set the audio *mode* to `MODE_IN_CALL` when using the voice call stream (like this: `AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)`).  If you find that is required, then you need to make sure you return the mode to `MODE_NORMAL` once playback completes, otherwise whenever you press the volume hard keys, it'll say "In-call volume"!  However, if and when you do want to change back to `MODE_NORMAL`, you must check that a genuine phone call isn't happening at that time...

Maybe you could use another stream type rather than the voice call one, but I'm just speaking from experience working on an app that could use either the speakerphone or the earpiece for audio playback, which *requires* the use of the voice call stream.

Like I said, audio handling isn't particularly fun... ;)

Comment: Thanks Christopher, your advice was spot on.  I've actually hijacked, the STREAM_ALARM, which suits my purpose, set it to solo and this has the desired effect.  Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops, not such a good idea, at least not with headphones.  Back to VOICE_CALL.  Don't seem to  need MODE_IN_CALL, at least not so far.

Answer (score 6):

It has been 2 years. But I hope this could help someone:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

**Note:** if you call [setStreamMute(int, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute(int,%20boolean)) to mute the stream **n** times, you must call it **n** times again to unmute (use `false`).

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate way is to use the `AudioManager.requestAudioFocus(...)` method

See
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#requestAudioFocus%28android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: The only problem with this is if other apps don't honour the audio focus request.

Comment: true, though if you use the TRANSIENT flags, most will. We should all strive to be good audio focus citizens!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AudioManager.adjustVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) method:

```
AudioManager audioMan = 
    (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioMan.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,
    AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```