# android headphones/pressy button plugged prevents phone dial keys sound

Tags: android, android-intent

I have recently purchased a pressy button and I try a few things with it.
I am able to listen for pressy clicks using a media_button receiver.

However I noticed that when I plug the pressy button into the device headphones slot, and then I try to make a call, the dial clicks sounds are gone.
Most likely the device is acting like the headphones are connected, so sound does not go to speakers.

I have found this post :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834816/is-there-any-way-to-force-audio-through-the-speakers-when-headphones-are-plugged)

but the solution there is not suitable for me, because if I force audio to mode_call, then my receiver is no longer receiving pressy clicks.

I know this is possible because there is an app on playstore, Klick, that is able to do this.

Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but I noticed that sometimes on a Samsung device it has no effect. Then suddenly the sound is played in device speakers when headphones are plugged.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), BroadcastReceiverPressyButton.class.getName()));

// Force audio through the speakers when pressy button is plugged in
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```