# Force output sound to internal speaker while headphones plugged in

Tags: android, microphone

How do I make the internal phone speaker play sound while plugging in my headphones? I see that it's possible by using the [SoundAbout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix&hl=en) app.

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834816/is-there-any-way-to-force-audio-through-the-speakers-when-headphones-are-plugged) which suggests

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

I may have done it in the wrong way. I'm just setting that and using the MediaPlayer to play some music.

I'm using Nexus 6 to do this test.

Comment: Did you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6847737/4310784)? I had same problem and it saved me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to force audio through the speakers when headphones are plugged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834816/is-there-any-way-to-force-audio-through-the-speakers-when-headphones-are-plugged)

Comment: @MohammadZ It doesn't work for me. I'm using Marshmaellow btw.

Answer (score 1):

Hello use this instead:

```
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_CURRENT);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

I am using the Nexus 6 device as well. Hope this helps!