# Switching between phone speaker and wired headset

Tags: android

I'm a total novice with programming for Android. I am trying to build a multimedia player app and I wanted to add option to switch between wired headset and speaker on button press - while I know this option is rather redundant, project requirements force me to implement such functionality.

I already tried all the suggested ideas from this thread:
[Is there any way to force audio through the speakers when headphones are plugged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834816/is-there-any-way-to-force-audio-through-the-speakers-when-headphones-are-plugged)

I added permission MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS to manifest.

I do believe my mistake may be caused by not fully understanding some of the mechanics, I'm using, but I thought it won't hurt to ask for help here, here's my code for player activity in my app:

```
package com.example.ja.multimedia_player;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class PlayActivity extends Activity {

    String title2;
    ArrayList<String> mediaList;
    String indeks;
    Integer licznik;
    String blokada;
    Long blok;
    Button button;

    private AudioManager myAudioManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    Button musicOutputDevice = (Button)findViewById (R.id.device); // deklaracja przycisku do zmiany trybu odtwarzania


    //listener na guziku do zmiany urządzenia

    musicOutputDevice.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            private AudioManager m_amAudioManager;
            m_amAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
            m_amAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);



/*            AudioSystem audioSystem = new AudioSystem ();


            if (myAudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn())
            {myAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);}
            else
            {myAudioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);}

*/


        }

        });




    VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    //pobranie listy utworów
    mediaList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");




    //pobranie aktualnego utworu

    title2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("musicPath");
    String viewSource =title2;
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    indeks = getIntent().getStringExtra("indeks");
    licznik = Integer.parseInt(indeks);
    blokada = getIntent().getStringExtra("blokada");
    //blok = Long.parseLong(blokada);
    Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this,
            blokada,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(viewSource));
    myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(myVideoViewCompletionListener);
    myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(MyVideoViewPreparedListener);
    myVideoView.setOnErrorListener(myVideoViewErrorListener);

    myVideoView.requestFocus();
    myVideoView.start();
}

// nasłuch końca utworu

    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener myVideoViewCompletionListener
            = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this,
                    "Koniec",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            title2=mediaList.get(licznik + 1);



            VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(title2));


            myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(myVideoViewCompletionListener);
            myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(MyVideoViewPreparedListener);
            myVideoView.setOnErrorListener(myVideoViewErrorListener);

            myVideoView.requestFocus();
            myVideoView.start();

            licznik = licznik + 1;



        }};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to crack this one on my own, but I will post the part that was wrong, so someone with similliar problem might use it.

I was trying to use an example for application that wasn't a media player, thus `set(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL)` was not right for this.

Correct code for my onClickListener is:

```
public void onClick (View v) {
            AudioManager myAudioManager;
            myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            if (myAudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn())
            {musicOutputDevice.setText("Słuchawki");
            myAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);}
            else
            {musicOutputDevice.setText("Głośnik");
            myAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
            myAudioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(true);}
```

Anyway, thank you guys for posting so many useful advices in other threads! This page is awesome! Hope I'll learn even more while being here :)