# AudioManager's isSpeakerphoneOn() returning false in onCreate()

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

My app needs to know early on at [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) whether the headset is plugged in or not (if it isn't, it should simply display a dialog and exit, as this is a **headset-only app**, not to be used with a speaker).

Because registering a receiver for ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG or ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY is recommended to be done in either onStart() or onResume(), relying on these messages in onCreate is out of question.

So, I turned instead to Audio Manager's [isSpeakerphoneOn()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isSpeakerphoneOn()) with the hope that my app's onCreate() will find it reflecting the correct status of the speakerphone.

Unfortunately however, [isSpeakerphoneOn()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isSpeakerphoneOn()) always return `false`, despite the speakerphone being on and nothing else plugged in (neither wired nor bluetooth headset).

My questions are:

1. Why? What are the conditions for this [isSpeakerphoneOn()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isSpeakerphoneOn()) method to **correctly** reflect the phone's status?

   2. Is there a way to determine in [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) whether the headset is plugged in or not?

Comment: This [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12508703/5556250) suggests that you are out of luck. There simply isn't adequate support for this in the current Android API.