# setSpeakerphoneOn() not working on 2.1, working on 2.3

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager, audiotrack, speakerphone

I need to play some audio through the earpiece. I am using AudioTrack to play some sound on a device. and the audio mode is set as STREAM_VOICE_CALL.
Also, in my activity, the speakerphone is turned off by:

```
AudioManager am;            
am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

This seems to work perfectly on 2.3 devices. But on 2.1, sound is still played from the speaker.

As a fix for this, I tried using setMode() as:

```
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

With this, the sound was played through the earpiece for 2.1 and 2.3, but most times not played at all by 2.3.
Also, I read at some places that the setMode() should not be used by apps as it affects the system-wide phone state.
here : http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/issues/detail?id=270

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Below 2.3, Android has been a little buggy with `setSpeakerPhoneOn()`.  As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663831/342745), I think you'll need to use both API methods.

In regards to 2.3 audio not being played at all, check your in-call volume settings (which is what will be used).  Try and keep track of the state the phone was in before using `setMode()` as well, perhaps setting it back to `MODE_NORMAL` once the audio manager is no longer being used.

Comment: I did set it back to MODE_NORMAL. still the issue.
I guess I'll have to live with the application being 2.3+ or buggy on 2.1.
setmode() is not at all recommended for such applications (check the link in my question edit)

Comment: Because the routing methods are deprecated, I don't think there's any other solution, unless you use them specifically for 2.2-.  It could be a bug with the phone you're using as well, btw, like an incomplete audio driver or something.