# Can I use phonegap to play audio through the earpiece speaker?

Tags: android, html, cordova

Can anyone please show me how and where can I modify the Phonegap source to play audio through the earpiece?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
private AudioManager m_amAudioManager;  
m_amAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  
m_amAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); 
m_amAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

Also need to add new permission:

```
MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
```

Either put this code in your activity start (`onCreate()`) or you need to write a plugin to enable/disable it based on your requirement from the javascript.

Check this post for more 
[Android - Getting audio to play through earpiece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119060/android-getting-audio-to-play-through-earpiece)

Comment: hi, where exactly do i put this in the phonegap source?