# play audio through earpiece

Tags: android, quickblox

I have the OnQBVideoChatListener from QuickBlox SDK for Android set as follow:

```
OnQBVideoChatListener qbVideoChatListener = new OnQBVideoChatListener() {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onOpponentAudioDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
        QBVideoChatController.getInstance().playAudio(audioData); 
    }
    ...
}
```

The playAudio method is currently playing what the opponent says through the speaker.
How do I make it to play through earpiece?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960313/android-play-audio-from-earpiece

Answer (score 0):

Audio should be played through earpiece when you plug earpiece. Android switches it by itself. Did you try it ?

Comment: "earpiece" in this context probably refers to the small built-in speaker located at the top front of the phone.