# Android - SpeechRecognizer and wired headset

Tags: android, bluetooth, speech-recognition, headset

I want use wired headset as audio source for `SpeechRecognizer`. I read questions like [Android - Getting audio to play through earpiece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119060/android-getting-audio-to-play-through-earpiece) and [Android - Play audio from earpiece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960313/android-play-audio-from-earpiece/). Finally i come to:

```
public void holdAudioStream(){
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
}

public void releaseAudioStream(){
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
}
```

but this don't work. Problem solved for Bluetooth headset by using

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
```

I'm not found alternative `audioManager.startBluetoothSco();` for wired headset. Is there a possibility combination `SpeechRecognizer` and wired headset?

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same requirement. In my application as well I am using Google Speech recognition but want to take input from headset mic. But SpeechRecognizer does not have any api for it but MediaRecoder in android do have that api. So solution is that record voice using MediaRecorder and send that file to Google Speech to text server and get the response. You can refer to below links :

Android app -
https://github.com/katchsvartanian/voiceRecognition

Documentation - 
https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2

I tried to run android app but its giving me some runtime exception.

Please also let me know if you could find solution for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can only make 50 requests per day using "google-speech-v2" (does not meet the technical task).