# How to force streaming sound to a phone earspeaker?

Tags: soundpool

I'm making a little voice stream application on android and I play a sound with a certain frequency to emulate the ringing sound for the caller.
The problem is that the sound always comes from the phone's speaker and I'd like to force the sound stream to go to the earpiece.
I'm using the soundpool object to play the media file and I've just red that it was possible with audiomanager but I've seen nothing for soundpool.
Is it possible anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Silly question sorry, I thought that using AudioManager implies using MediaPlayer. It's OK now.
Got what I wanted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663831/1830043