# is there any method to play audio on earpeace instead of media player speakers in android

Tags: android

`
The smaller speaker inside a phone that produces a low volume sound which can only be heard when listing closely with your ear against the phone.

MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.test /* .mp3 file*/);

mplayer.play();`

Comment: What do you mean by reciever speaker??

Comment: i mean it is phone speaker instead of hands free speaker

Comment: The smaller speaker inside a phone that produces a low volume sound which can only be heard when listing closely with your ear against the phone.

Comment: I think it is a user selection thing. You can output the sound, but the system (android core) sends it to the *right* userselected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Getting audio to play through earpiece](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119060/android-getting-audio-to-play-through-earpiece)