# Making exoPlayer 2.0 to play through a speakerphone

Tags: android, exoplayer, audiotrack

So I'm working on an alarm clock app and I have a trouble with making exoplayer to use speakerphone when I have earphones jack in the device. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119060/android-getting-audio-to-play-through-earpiece), but as comments says it's not actually a reliable way to do this. I also found that somebody had a similar problem [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/755) and that there is a method `SimpleExoPlayer.setAudioStreamType()`, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work in ExoPlayer 2.0.4. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution! When you create an exoPlayer you can either use the default renderers (that is what `ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance()` for) or create your own renderers to do something specific. The problem with the default audio renderer (which is `MediaCodecAudioRenderer`) is that it has `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` set by default and ExoPlayer 2.x doesn't have any methods to change it (although there was such a method in ExoPlayer 1.x).

In order to fix that I had to create my own audio renderer and pass `AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM` as one of its parameters. After that, you can use `ExoPlayerFactory.newInstance()` to and pass the created renderer to it.

Here's a class that you can use to get an instance of ExoPlayer that will always play music through the speaker phone. It will also use the alarm volume level.

```
public class AlarmExoPlayerFactory {

    public static ExoPlayer newInstance() {
        Renderer[] renderers = new Renderer[1];

        Renderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioRenderer(MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT, null, true,
                null, null, null, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        renderers[0] = audioRenderer;

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(handler);
        return ExoPlayerFactory.newInstance(renderers, trackSelector);
    }
}
```