# Android - Can't get audio to play through my Earpiece

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm having an app that is using the phone speaker, to play audio normally.

I'm having a button that once pressed will pass the audio
to the phone as in call / BT headset if it's connected.

but no matter what i do i can't get the audio to move to my headset.
here is what i do in case of a press on the move to phone button.

```
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, mVolume, 0);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

in addition i made sure i have the
`Modify_Audio_Settings` permission

I only managed to get the call moved to the Phone Itself. and i can hear the audio as in a phone call

but i can't hear it in my BT Headphones that are connected to my phone

what am i doing wrong?

p.s.
i noticed a similar question :
[Android - Getting audio to play through earpiece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119060/android-getting-audio-to-play-through-earpiece)

but it's not my case 1-1 and i looked into the solutions there it's the same what i'm doing.

what am i doing wrong an how can i fix it ?

Comment: Try AudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn()

Comment: @Qing that doesn't work